# OpenBUGS322 to R communication

Tags: r

I have a basic question on trying to make OpenBUGS322 run with R using R2OpenBUGS.

When running several trial scripts (see one example below) I get an error

Error in matrix(, n.sims, n.parameters) :
  invalid 'nrow' value (too large or NA)

Through a search I found that other people experienced this with OpenBUGS322 and OpenBUGS321 should work fine. HOWEVER, could anybody advice where could I find older version. 
I need OpenBUGS321setup.exe and cannot find it anywhere.

(I have fixed several other issues such as dbus config, and the OpenBUGS opens now when prompted from XQuartz)

Here is more info to find out whether I am on the right path.

I am running versions:
Mac OS X  10.5.8
Wine 1.4.1
XQuartz 2.6.3
OpenBUGS322

Trial code from WinBUGS textbook with added path for WINE and OpenBUGS (not 100% sure if correct)

Thanks a lot for any help.

Script:

```
y10<-rnorm(n=10, mean=600, sd=30)
y1000<-rnorm(n=1000, mean=600, sd=30)
summary(lm(y1000~1))
library(R2OpenBUGS)

#setwd("/Users/Pavel/wine/ProgramFiles/OpenBUGS322")
setwd("/Users/Pavel/Documents/R/OpenBUGS")
sink("model.txt")
 cat("
model{
population.mean~dunif(0,5000)
precision<-1/population.variance
population.variance<-population.sd* population.sd
 population.sd~dunif(0,100)
for(i in 1:nobs){
 mass[i]~dnorm(population.mean, precision)
}
}
", fill=TRUE)
 sink()

WINE="/opt/local/bin/wine"
WINEPATH="/opt/local/bin/winepath"
OpenBUGS.pgm="/Users/Pavel/wine/ProgramFiles/OpenBUGS322/OpenBUGS.exe"

#Package the data to be handed to OpenBUGS
win.data<-list(mass=y1000, nobs=length(y1000))

#Function to generate starting values
inits<-function()
list(population.mean=rnorm(1,600), population.sd=runif(1,1,30))

#Parameters to be monitored
params<-c("population.mean", "population.sd", "population.variance")

#MCMC settings
nc<-3     #Number of chains
ni<-1000  #Number of draws for each chain
nb<-1     #number of draws to discard as burn -in
nt<-1     #Thinning rate

out<-bugs(data=win.data, inits=inits, parameters.to.save=params, model.file="model.txt",    n.thin=nt, n.chains=nc, n.burnin=nb, n.iter=ni, OpenBUGS.pgm=OpenBUGS.pgm, WINE=WINE,     WINEPATH=WINEPATH,useWINE=T)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you use `rjags` instead? Syntax is almost the same:

```
require(rjags)

modelstring <- "
    model {
        for(i in 1:nobs){
            mass[i] ~ dnorm(m, prec) # precision
        }
        m ~ dunif(0, 5000)
        prec <- 1/sqrt(SD) # convert to Std Deviation
        SD ~ dunif(0, 100)
    }
"
writeLines(modelstring,con="model.txt")

y1000 <- stats::rnorm(n=1000, mean=600, sd=30)

dataList <- list(
    mass = y1000,
    nobs = length(y1000)
    )

initsList <-  list(
    m = stats::rnorm(n=1, mean=600, sd=1),
    SD = stats::runif(n=1, min=1, max=30)
    )

parameters <- c("m","SD") # to be monitored.
adaptSteps <- 100         #  "tune" the samplers.
burnInSteps <- 100        #  "burn-in" the samplers.
nChains <- 3              # Number of chains to run.
numSavedSteps <-2000      # Total number of steps in chains to save.
thinSteps <- 1            # Number of steps to "thin" (1=keep every step).
nPerChain <- ceiling(( numSavedSteps * thinSteps ) / nChains) # Steps per chain

jagsModel <- rjags::jags.model(
    "model.txt", data=dataList,
    inits=initsList, n.chains=nChains,
    n.adapt=adaptSteps)

stats::update(jagsModel, n.iter=burnInSteps)

MCMC1 <- as.matrix(rjags::coda.samples(
    jagsModel, variable.names=parameters,
    n.iter=nPerChain, thin=thinSteps))

SDsample <- matrix(MCMC1[,grep("SD",colnames(MCMC1))],
                ncol=length(grep("SD",colnames(MCMC1))))
```

You can then convert to variance with:

```
SDsample^2
```

If you're looking for OpenBUGS321setup.exe you should be able to find it [here](http://www.openbugs.info/w/Downloads). I note that it hasn't been well tested under WINE. Is a Linux emulator a possibility?